# MySQL count how many records has user made

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, min

I'm trying to count how many records has unique player [auth] made.
So basically I'm trying to select lowest time on every map and count who has most entries left.

I got this far with a lot of googling.

```
SELECT
    auth,
    map,
    MIN(time) AS Record
FROM
    bhop.playertimes
WHERE track LIKE '0'
GROUP BY
    map
)
```

This successfully lists every maps top time and [auth] who made the record.
What would be easiest way to sum the [auth] entries?

I would prefer this type answer query:

[auth] [records_made]

[image: Database structure]

[image: Query result]

Comment: please add data as text and or dbfiddle see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want:

```
select p.auth, count(*) no_records
from bhop.playertimes p
where 
    p.track = 0
    and p.time = (
        select min(p1.time) 
        from bhop.playertimes p1 
        where p1.map = p.map and p1.track = 0
    )
```

This gives you the number of `map`s per `auth` where they own the minimum time (which, as I understand, is your definition of an `auth` having made *the record*).

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can get the same result with window function `rank()`:

```
select auth, count(*) no_records
from (
    select auth, rank() over(partition by map order by time) rn
    from bhop.playertimes
    where track = 0
) p
group by auth
```